# Posting and deleting the first comment on a post causes the comment to be shown until page refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Add comment to a post (be the first commenter; that's important)
- Delete that comment

**Problem:**

The comment is deleted as expected (i.e. visiting the page in a new tab shows the comment no longer exists), but there is no indication of this client side and it remains shown until you refresh the page.

[image]

**Environments:**

Chrome 62.0.3202.75
Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit)
IE 11.0.9600.18816IS
Edge 41.16299.15.0
iPad Safari on latest iOS  11.0.3

Comment: Had the same thing just today; very confusing.

Comment: fyi, I just reproduced the issue with **Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit)** and **IE 11.0.9600.18816IS** (...not that this seems like a particularly urgent issue, and I didn't notice it until I saw this question.)

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I've noticed today that the new comment comment indicator isn't always showing. It just happened to me right now, and while my browser window showed nothing, the mobile app pinged as the comment had tagged me. Anyone else notice this?

Comment: I had this earlier today.

Comment: Could you please add a higher resolution screenshot?

Comment: This must of been something that crept up through some new feature because this used to work correctly.

Comment: @JonH, hence bug report rather than feature request ;) Few days ago it worked.

Comment: @Victoria - Well you never mentioned that it worked before in your email.  And I find bugs that have never been reported ever...does that mean they are feature requests -  I still consider a link you click on where the dialog box doesn't open a bug even if it never opened.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that was the best I could come up with using free online conversion tools i could find.

Comment: [Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/Tor0n7mMK)

Comment: Error is `cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ru.js?v=313e2d72d793:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined`

Comment: @vp_arth, [here](https://i.imgur.com/HFwWauJ.png), to be more precise. I haven't mention that as I believe that SE developers are having good debugging tools (better than Google Chrome console).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A typo snuck in a number of changesets back. I'm building the fix out right now.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you for the fix! Works again.